# Removing Blank Lines From Powershell Output

Tags: powershell

I have searched for an answer to this and have not found something that has worked for me yet.

I have a Powershell script that is being used in Tripwire to assess the IIS version of a server. The value is returned, but it can't be interpreted by Tripwire because of blank lines, I believe.

Kindly see the code below. Thank you in advance!

```
%Windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe    "$ErrorActionPreference='SilentlyContinue'; $iv=(get-itemproperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\  | select setupstring | ft -hidetableheaders); if ($iv.length -gt 0 | where {$_.versionstring -ne ""} ) { echo $iv } else { Write-Host -NoNewline "Not Installed" }"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the extra lines is this: `|ft -hidetableheaders`

Just grab the `Setupstring` property value directly with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty setupstring`:

```
$iv = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\ | Select -ExpandProperty setupstring;
```

---

The expression `$iv.length -gt 0| where {$_.versionstring -ne ""}` doesn't make to much sense, and is exactly equivalent to `$iv.length -gt 0`.

You can simplify the if statement by just testing `$iv`:

```
if ($iv) { 
    Write-Host $iv -NoNewline
} else {
    Write-Host 'Not Installed' -NoNewline 
}
```

So the line becomes:

```
%Windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "$ErrorActionPreference='SilentlyContinue';$iv=Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\ | Select -Expand setupstring; if ($iv) { Write-Host $iv -NoNewline} else { Write-Host 'Not Installed' -NoNewline }"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly! This saved me at work.